# Why does my while loop never end, even while the produced integer fails the conditions to run

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to do a simple while loop that searches a string for a specific character then returns each place the character appears in the string before ending the loop

Here is a version of my code, where I have been trying to catch when the point where the number is no longer either 0, or less than the length of the string, as I couldn't get the while loop to end without the if statement, I tried adding it in to force 'num' to be outside these bounds and see if the while loop conditions would catch it and end the loop, seemingly not.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
        string phrase = "Hello I am a pineapple";
        
        int phraseLength = int(phrase.length());
        int num = 0;
        
        
        while(num < phrase.length() -1 && num > -1)
        {
            num = int(phrase.find('a', num));
            cout << num << endl;
            num++;
            if(num < phraseLength -1 || num ==0){
                cout << num << endl;
            }else{
                num = 24;
            }
        
        }
```

I'm more used to python and currently trying to learn c++, I know if I were to use these conditions in python, the loop would end, so why not here?

Sample output:

```
9
11
12
17
18
-1
0
8
9
11
12
17
18
-1
0
8
9
11
12
17
18
-1
0
8
9
11
12
17
18
-1
0
8
9
11
12
17
18
-1
0
8
9
11
12
17
18
-1
0
8
9
11
12
17
18
-1
0
8
9
11
12
17
18
-1
0
```

Comment: Did you perhaps use return? return can exit the loop if i'm correct

Comment: Also, you didn't include "string" in your source code, you could use const char* if you don't want to do that, but only use that if you promise not to edit it.

Comment: You added return to the end of int main, i didn't exactly mean that. What i meant was this:
    while(num < phrase.length() -1 && num > -1)
    
    {
            num = int(phrase.find('a', num));

            cout << num << endl;

            num++;

            if(num < phraseLength -1 || num ==0){
                cout << num << endl;
                return 0;
            }else{
                num = 24;
            }
        
        }

Comment: Hey, so I realised I missed off the bottom of my code, I've edited it to show my full code. it did include ```return 0``` but having that return in there doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I will make an answer, i am not good at explaining.

Comment: I hope this makes sense

Comment: i make a small suggestion for my answer, hope its enough.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it turns out I was wrong, but it was to do with how it evaluates the code, I posted an answer to my question below, I feel even more of an idiot now.

Comment: Got it! Sorry if I introduced iterators too early.

Comment: Hey, no problem, I have used them in python, but it was bugging me why this didn't seem to work, I think I'm just used to the very specific error codes in python that will tell you exactly what you did wrong. Your solution would definitely work better, but I was just frustrated with what I thought was a simple loop

Comment: I'd suggest either reading Programming and Practices using c++ or the C++ Programming Language. Both could be helpful as they describe the langauge a bit more than i can

Comment: For problems like this, the usual way to help solve them is by using a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop has no exit condition because you don't test the return value of `std::string::find` properly.

If you [read the manual](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/), you'll see that the return value when no match is found is `std::string::npos`.
Don't expect it to have any other value than the constant provided by the STL, or you'll be sorry.

This will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>    // include what you need instead of relying on other includes
//using namespace std; <--- don't do this unless you know exactly what you're doing
//                          (which is unlikely given your limited acquantaince with C++)
int main(void) // "void" is optional, but indicates (argc,argv) have been purposely ignored
{
    std::string phrase = "a Hello I am a pineapple a"; // test edge cases when possible
                                                       // (here, the first and last chars)
    size_t position = 0;  // "num" is a terrible variable name, like "int someint"
                          // and the proper type to use is size_t (unsigned).
                          // Using an int will get you a warning.
                          // Ignore warnings at your own risk...
    while (true)
    {
        position = phrase.find('a', position);    // look for the character
        if (position == std::string::npos) break; // exit condition
        std::cout << position << std::endl;       // display found occurrences
        position++; // move to next character (or end of string)
    }
}
```

Or if `for` loops are more your thing, you can slightly reduce the code like so:

```
for (size_t position = 0 ; ; position++)
{
    position = phrase.find('a', position);
    if (position == std::string::npos) break;
    std::cout << position << std::endl;
}
```

Some people find that nicer, some harder to read.
I rather like it because it makes `position` local to the loop, preventing you from doing something unwise like reusing the variable outside the loop.
It's really a matter of preference.

Comment: can you remove the ```void``` in ```int main```  as its not required by c++ and might be confusing.

Comment: Why would I do that? It does indicate that I purposely ignored the arguments. C++ is obfuscated enough as it is, I won't miss a chance to make the code less ambiguous :)

Comment: Well, someone who is new to c++ may think that the ```void``` is required. You can add to the comments that void is not really required. I'm only thinking in terms of a new person introduced to c++

Comment: OK, I can do that :)

Comment: also (please excuse this comment, its late for me) would ```if (position)``` work?

Comment: also i didnt even catch that you used int instead of size_t, glad you did.

Comment: At first I tried to stay close to the OP version, but in the end I'd rather fix the remaining quirks.

Comment: Wait, did you use a different find? Because the last time i used it, it returned an iterator Never mind, i just figured out.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that (like @kalyanswaroop said) when find() cannot find a character it returns -1, the next step in the loop changes the assigned value from -1 to 0, and so it satisfies the conditions of the loop. In order to prevent this from happening I changed the code to the below, so that if num is -1, it breaks the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string phrase = "Hello I am a pineapple";
    
    int phraseLength = int(phrase.length() - 1);
    int num = 0;
    
    
    while(num >= 0)
    {
        
        num = int(phrase.find(char('a'), num));
        if(num > -1)
        {
            cout << num << endl;
            num++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }

    }
  
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Nope. `find()` returns `std::string::npos`. Using hard coded values instead of STL provided constants is a most terrible idea. You'll get away with it more often than not, but the day you won't, you'll be in for a world of pain.

Comment: Ah, and I’m assuming when you use int( std::string::npos), that’s when it’s changed to -1?

Comment: Feel free to disregard my remark. You and possibly your coworkers will be the ones to suffer for trying to outsmart the STL...

Comment: Lol, I mean it’s just a hobby atm, I’m going through a C++ course atm and I like to make up random programs based on what I’ve learned so far. But they’re likely to often miss a lot of complexities about the language, but I do feel like I learn a lot in my struggles

Comment: SO is supposedly an educational site, so I'd rather avoid giving advices to beginners like "hey, don't bother with STL constants, I know for a fact npos is really just -1". C++ is the worst bug factory around. Even doing everything by the book, any piece of C++ code is likely to crash and burn if you only look at it sideways. Cutting corners with this language is not a wise thing to do.

Comment: @AlexGadd You're right about the conversion converting `std::string::npos` to `-1`. If you're interested in the details, you can look them up here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Numeric_conversions

Answer (score 0):

### **Suggestion: Change your code**

Here is a few suggestions

### **Using `find()`**

---

The by far easiest way to do this is by using `Find()` (Thanks to neko for suggesting this. Not sure if he really suggested that)

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> //Don't know if this is required
int main()
{
     string phrase = "Hello I am a pineapple";
     auto location = std::find(phrase.begin(), phrase.end(), 'a');
     cout << *location;
}
```

### **Creating a function like `find()`**

---

Another way to do this (also to get a taste on how `find()` might be implemented) is by writting a function similar to `find()`

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template<typename Iterator, typename T>
Iterator Find_Character(Iterator begin, Iterator end, T Find)
{
   while (begin != end && *begin != Find) ++begin;
   return begin;
}

int main()
{
    string phrase = "Hello I am a pineapple";
    auto location = Find_Character(phrase.begin(), phrase.end(), 'a');
    std::cout << "Found character: " << *location << endl; 
}
```

Comment: perhaps you meant to say break instead of return 0 to exit the loop ?

Comment: well i am used to return. Sorry

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, it almost works, but not quite, ideally the answer would be:
``` 8
9
11
12
17
```
but instead with the answer you gave, it ends at 9. The issue seems to be with the number not meeting the conditions, if for example I use ```phrase.find(char('a'), 18)```  (the string is 22 characters long) it returns a value of 18446744073709551615, I don't know if this helps?

Comment: I made a small issue

Comment: I assume that you want to find a character in string as that makes the most sense.

Comment: I am currently re-working my code so it works with what you want.

Comment: I worked out the issue, it's the logic, because the while loop is evaluating "num < 22 && num > -1" it will always return TRUE. as a result it will never break the loop. Sorry for being such an idiot -_-

Comment: Its alright, I am not used to what you do.

Comment: That is why I use pointers to point to locations in memory, its easier to read.

Comment: An unnecessary use of iterators, complete with templates and stl shenanigans that leads to more complicated and ultimately buggy code. `std::string` offers a perfectly good `find` method. Why would you want to rewrite your own (buggy) version?

Comment: I wanted to write something different from find. Its late for me at the moment.

Comment: I fixed my earlier solution and used your suggestion.

Comment: ik its slightly different. Wanted to suggest an idea

Answer (score 0):

when the phrase.find cant find 'a', it returns -1, and then you have num++ which brings num back to the same condition as the beginning.
Perhaps you should do something like:

```
while(num < phrase.length() -1 && num > -1)
{
    int findPos = int(phrase.find('a', num));
    if(findPos != nPos) //nPos is defined as -1
    {
            num = findPos ;
    }
    else
    {
            break ;
    }
    cout << num << endl;
    num++;

}
```

Comment: You don't need an intermediate variable here. More variables -> more complicated code -> more potential bugs.

Comment: Sure. I saw your code above. It is well written. I was trying to show the OP where he made the mistake. I was not trying to rewrite the entire code. Perhaps I just had to mention the text I had above the code to show where the error was and didnt have to type any code !

Comment: Sure, I get the idea. But, what with SO being supposedly an educational site, might as well try to write a nice piece of C++ (assuming that is even possible :) ).